# ClickHouse syntax error on cluster when importing CSV

Tags: clickhouse

So I have the strangest thing happening with ClickHouse CSV import.

We have a CSV (TabSeparated) file (about 25M, 40k lines, many columns). When I load it to a local ClickHouse, it's loading all right. When we try to load it to a 3 server cluster, we get the following error:

> Code: 62. DB::Exception: Syntax error: failed at position 321 ('some_field') (line 4, col 264): some_field = 'AIR' FORMAT JSON. Expected one of: token, DoubleColon, MOD, DIV, NOT, BETWEEN, LIKE, ILIKE, NOT LIKE, NOT ILIKE, IN, NOT IN, GLOBAL IN, GLOBAL NOT IN, IS, AND, OR, QuestionMark, alias, AS, GROUP BY, WITH, HAVING, WINDOW, ORDER BY, LIMIT, OFFSET, SETTINGS, UNION, EXCEPT, INTERSECT, INTO OUTFILE, FORMAT, end of query.

Which just doesn't really make sense.

The command to load is the same for both environments:

`cat file.tsv|docker run -i --rm clickhouse/clickhouse-server clickhouse-client --host=the.host --query="INSERT INTO default.mytable FORMAT TabSeparated"`

What is even more strange is that if I split the input file into two parts, it loads to the cluster as well.

(The table format is MergeTree / ReplicatedMergeTree.)